# How to achieve 0 (train and test) loss on the 4th dataset at tensorflow playground?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, demo

TensorFlow playground: https://playground.tensorflow.org

Assuming 0 noise the other 3 simpler datasets are easy but the 4th spiral one seems very hard to fit perfectly within the limit of 6 layers even to use all 
7 feature inputs.

Answer (score 0):

you can cheat a little bit and use theta and r

theta is arctan(y,x)

r is sqrt(x^2+y^2)

but basically you can use x1 x2 sin(x1) and sin(x2) too, with a tuned model